# No loader is configured for ".node" files

Tags: node.js, vite, nodejs-polars

I am getting this error when trying to load nodejs-polars into a React Vite application. Does anyone know how to get this to load properly?

```
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../node_modules/.pnpm/nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu@0.7.4/node_modules/nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu/nodejs-polars.linux-x64-gnu.node

    ../../node_modules/.pnpm/nodejs-polars@0.7.4/node_modules/nodejs-polars/bin/native-polars.js:182:52:
      182 │ ...                  nativeBinding = require('nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu');
          ╵                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../node_modules/.pnpm/nodejs-polars-linux-x64-musl@0.7.4/node_modules/nodejs-polars-linux-x64-musl/nodejs-polars.linux-x64-musl.node

    ../../node_modules/.pnpm/nodejs-polars@0.7.4/node_modules/nodejs-polars/bin/native-polars.js:168:52:
      168 │ ...                 nativeBinding = require('nodejs-polars-linux-x64-musl');
          ╵                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["nodejs-polars-linux-x64-musl", "nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu"] }
```

Comment: Can you explain how to reproduce this more minimally? It seems odd that it's trying to load a `.node` file.

Comment: I just installed this package: https://github.com/pola-rs/nodejs-polars

Answer (score 1):

`nodejs-polars` is a server side library you will not be able to load it into a React app.